# Como posso filtrar dois valores em minha array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, json, array, axios

Olá! estou tendo problemas em entender como posso filtrar a resposta que obtenho do meu banco de dados, a lógica dele está desse jeito:

Eu recebo uma array de objetos do qual possui os valores de ***useridrelacao***, ***useridRequerente*** e ***useridRequerido***, o primeiro valor é apenas para saber qual situação está aquele laço de amizade, o que importa nesta situação é o que ocorre entre os dois valores.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O usuário que envia um pedido de amizade para outro usuário se torna o ***Requerente*** e o usuário que aceita esse pedido de amizade é o ***Requerido***. Neste caso acima, o usuário que está logado no meu sistema tem seu *id = **6***, portanto ele é o Requerente das duas primeiras relações e o Requerido da terceira relação visto que seu número pode ser encontrado nestes três valores mostrados acima.

Então meu objetivo é filtrar os ids ao contrário a este do qual o id do meu usuário pertence, ou seja, se ele é id igual a ***6***, para os indices de **0** e **1**, quero resgatar apenas o useridRequerido dos quais são ***2*** e ***4***, mas ao mesmo tempo quero resgatar o valor do useridRequerente, visto que no terceiro indíce desta array, o usuário de id 6 é o useridRequerido, portanto viria junto o valor do ***1***.

A primeira tentativa coerente na minha cabeça do qual fiz foi a de condicionar em um laço de *.filter()* com um include do id sobre um dos dois valores desta maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas o resultado sempre sai incompleto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mesmo equivale quando passo um ***&&*** na condição com useridRequerido, já utilizei outros laços como *.map()* ou *.every()* com condições quase iguais nesta array de resposta e ainda não tive o resultado que estou realmente esperando, qual forma devo fazer para que eu consiga filtrar nesta lógica acima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente, você precisa **resgatar o objeto que inclua o ID que deseja, independente de ser requerido ou requerente para assim filtrar os outros IDs relacionados a ele**.

Você pode tentar algo como:

```
function filterByRelatedId(id, array) {
    return array.filter(objeto =>  {
        let requerente = objeto.useridRequerente === id;
        let requerido = objeto.useridRequerido === id;
        if (objeto.useridrelacao === 2 && (requerente || requerido)){
            return objeto;
        }
    });
}
```

Ou caso queira resgatar apenas os IDs (acredito que não seja esse o caso, pois não teria como diferenciar requerido de requerente):

```
function getOnlyIdsByFilteringRelatedId(id, array) {
    let arrayToReturn = [];
    let filteredArray = array.map(objeto =>  {
        let requerente = objeto.useridRequerente === id;
        let requerido = objeto.useridRequerido === id;
        if (objeto.useridrelacao === 2 && (requerente || requerido)){
            return requerido ? objeto.useridRequerente : objeto.useridRequerido;
        }
    });

    for (let objeto of filteredArray) {
        // Check for other properties here if wanted
        if (objeto) {
            arrayToReturn.push(objeto);
        }
    }

    return arrayToReturn;  
}
```

Escrevi as funções assumindo que um usuário não possa ser **requerido e requerente ao mesmo tempo**.

Comment: É justamente a segunda função que eu vi que eu realmente necessito, no entanto, ele me retorna *undefined* junto dos valores que preciso, existe como retornar só os valores sem estes *undefineds*?

Comment: @RafaelSoares A resposta foi editada para comportar sua pergunta. Basta uma segunda iteração na mesma função mas no array **já filtrado**, inserindo o que tiver valor (não seja `null`, `undefined` etc.) em um segundo array que retornará da função.